# Larger than 4GB file corrupted on Centos. How to extract?

Tags: linux, centos

I zipped a folder on centOS 5. It zipped up to around 4.1GB.

Now i am trying to unzip it but it gives error. I have tried a number of options. First with using the unzip command it says

[image]

then i tried to use

> jar xvf filename

as I found during research  that it can work. It works to extract some files but then give the following error.

[image]

finally I tried 7zip as an option. But it fails to giving the following error.

[image]

Here is some additional information.

Running the file command on the file gives

> site_backup_sep03_2015.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

running the stat command on it gives

[image]

is there a way to extract the file?

Comment: Have you tried `zcat` on the file to see if you get any sort of output?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have the 64bit version of java installed?  What filesystem type are you extracting to?  If you type "file site_backup_sep03_2015.zip" what do you see?   also use "stat" on the file.

Comment: @Aaron: No it is a 32-bit system.

Comment: Greater than 4 gig on a 32 bit box is problematic for lots of operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being on a 32bit system and using 32bit apps and/or using a version of unzip older than 6.0, you are likely hitting [one of these limits](http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html#limits)

Most likely this limit, "compressed size of a single file"  **4GB**

*In practice, the real limit may be 2 GB on many systems, due to UnZip's use of the fseek() function to jump around within an archive. Because's fseek's offset argument is usually a signed long integer, on 32-bit systems UnZip will not find any file that is more than 2 GB from the beginning of the archive. And on 64-bit systems, UnZip won't find any file that's more than 4 GB from the beginning (since the zipfile format can only store offsets that big). So the last file in the archive can potentially be arbitrarily large (in theory, anyway--we haven't tested this), but the combined total of all the rest must be less than 2 GB or 4 GB, respectively.*

So unfortunately, unless you can find another application that can read and decompress the file, then you would have to move to a 64 bit system or update your system to CentOS 7 which ships with unzip 6.0, or compile unzip 6.0 on your CentOS 5 machine and run it from your home directory perhaps.

From [unzip 6.0](http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html)

*[snip]..  Zip archive entries larger than 4 GiBytes*

Answer (score 3):

Make a ***copy*** of the file then try `zip -FF <filename>`.

From the man page (`man zip`)

```
-F    Fix the zip archive. This option can be used if some portions
      of the archive are missing. It is not guaranteed to work, so 
      you MUST make a backup of the original archive first.

      When  doubled as in -FF the compressed sizes given inside the
      damaged archive are not trusted and zip scans for special
      signatures to identify the limits between the archive members.
      The single -F is more reliable if the archive is not too much
      damaged, for example if it has only been truncated, so try this
      option  first.
```